# ImageView remove white border?

Tags: android, imageview, border

[image]

How to make this imageView full screen? No matter how I'm trying, I'm still getting that white borders on my phone, and on my emulator also, how to remove fully them?

Comment: is there anything about padding in your layout xml?

Comment: Paste the xml please.

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

Comment: remove all the padding

Comment: I found it sometimes better to programatically set images. imageview.setImageResource(int Resid)

Comment: Removing paddings worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"   
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

So those padding lines are your issue. They can be aesthetically pleasing at times, but in your case you want it to fill the whole view.

You can read more about padding in views here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html